# MacPorts: cgit install fails with "Unable to verify file checksums"

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macports, checksum, cgit

I tried to install cgit with MacPorts

```
# port install cgit
```

but it fails with:

```
Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for cgit-0.8.2.1.tar.bz2
Error: Checksum (sha1) mismatch for cgit-0.8.2.1.tar.bz2
Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for cgit-0.8.2.1.tar.bz2
Error: org.macports.checksum for port cgit returned:
       Unable to verify file checksums
```

I'm running Snow Leopard, Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549), Kernel Version: Darwin 10.8.0 64-bit

already did some online search and successfully updated ports

```
# port selfupdate
# port upgrade outdated
```

but it didn't solved the problem.

I also don't know if I should file a bugreport at MacPorts (Mac newbie with Linux background here) so instead I used the occasion for my first stackoverflow question ;)

Help is appreciated,

Alex

Comment: This may be temporary (try again, worked for me just now), some mirrors might be out of sync or broken.  I got the random mirror `http://lil.fr.distfiles.macports.org/git-core` where checksums were fine.  Failing that, see if someone on IRC can help you, or create a ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug at MacPorts.

I reported it: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/36083 and they kindly fixed it by updating cgit to the latest version.

Thanks nobody (amusing username) for feedback and Ryan for fixing it.